# Ansible YAML append to list under a key (?)

Tags: ansible, yaml

I have the following role variable called `groceries`:

```yaml
groceries:
  fruits:
    - name: 'Apples'
      cost: 100
    - name: 'Grapes'
      cost: 200
  vegetables:
    - name: 'Potatoes'
      cost: 120
  toiletries:
    - name: 'Toothpaste'
      cost: 20
```

These are used in a template.

Depending on the host and/or group, I want to append additional `vegetables`:

```yaml
groceries_additional:
  vegetables:
    - brand: 'Aubergine'
      cost: 100
```

Or append `fruits`:

```yaml
groceries_additional:
  fruits:
    - name: 'Blackberries'
      cost: 1000
```

I do not want to update the templates. Is there any way to append `groceries_additional` into `groceries`? This is my target result:

```yaml
groceries:
  fruits:
    - name: 'Apples'
      cost: 100
    - name: 'Grapes'
      cost: 200
    - name: 'Blackberries'
      cost: 1000
  vegetables:
    - name: 'Potatoes'
      cost: 120
    - brand: 'Aubergine'
      cost: 100
  toiletries:
    - name: 'Toothpaste'
      cost: 20
```

I tried to "merge" into `groceries` with the following, but it did not work (`groceries` did not change at all).

```yaml
- name: Merge
  set_fact:
    groceries: '{{ groceries_additional | combine(base_groceries, recursive=True) }}'
  vars:
    base_groceries: '{{ groceries | default({}) }}'
  when: groceries_additional is defined
```

Comment: There are a **lot** of ways of accomplishing that; which ones have you tried and what error are they producing for you?

Comment: I have edited the question with info on what I have tried. Thanks @mdaniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use option [*list_merge*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries), e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        groceries: "{{ groceries|combine(groceries_additional,
                                         recursive=True,
                                         list_merge='append') }}"
      vars:
        groceries_additional:
          vegetables:
            - brand: 'Aubergine'
              cost: 100
```

gives

```yaml
  groceries:
    fruits:
    - cost: 100
      name: Apples
    - cost: 200
      name: Grapes
    toiletries:
    - cost: 20
      name: Toothpaste
    vegetables:
    - cost: 120
      name: Potatoes
    - brand: Aubergine
      cost: 100
```

and consequent

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        groceries: "{{ groceries|combine(groceries_additional,
                                         recursive=True,
                                         list_merge='append') }}"
      vars:
        groceries_additional:
          fruits:
            - name: 'Blackberries'
              cost: 1000
```

gives the expected result

```yaml
  groceries:
    fruits:
    - cost: 100
      name: Apples
    - cost: 200
      name: Grapes
    - cost: 1000
      name: Blackberries
    toiletries:
    - cost: 20
      name: Toothpaste
    vegetables:
    - cost: 120
      name: Potatoes
    - brand: Aubergine
      cost: 100
```